# Can CmdArgs have flags outside of sub-modes?

Tags: parsing, haskell, command-line

I know that if there is a common flag among all of the sub-modes, it would be listed under "Common flags", but that flag still needs to come after the mode constructor.
Sometimes, there are flags that are related to the program instead of individual modes, so they should be able to be specified before the mode stuff (or even after). For example, my program can process tasks in parallel regardless of which mode it's running in. The number of parallel process is given by the "-n" flag, so the command line should be something like:

```
myprogram -n 4 MODE1 [flags/args-for-MODE1]
```

Could this be done in CmdArgs?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible, but there is a ticket to add it to CmdArgs: http://code.google.com/p/ndmitchell/issues/detail?id=457

It can be slightly more complicated, since if you have `MODE1` which takes `-n` with a required argument, and `MODE2` which takes `-n` with no argument, then what does the following mean:

```
 myprogram -n MODE2 MODE1
```

It could be mode `MODE1` and `-n` with the value `MODE2`, or it could be mode `MODE2` with the flag `-n` and the argument `MODE1`. I'm sure I'll figure out that when implementing the ticket though.

Comment: In your example, I assume MODE1 is a sub-mode of MODE2; if

Comment: Ignore my last comment, pressed enter accidentally. If `-n` takes a string value, I would assume I need to quote MODE2 for it to be unambiguous, if and only if, it is a flag of `myprogram`, not for mode `MODE1`. Basically, mode should only consider a flag if it comes after the mode constructor, and the closest mode constructor has higher precedence.

Comment: I think in the above example it would have to be MODE2, since if you wanted MODE1 you could always have done `-nMODE2 MODE1`